# How to Add Timeline Marker via Python?

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, timeline

I'd like to add a Timeline Marker via python script. How can I do it?

Using bpy.ops.clip.add_marker() requires me to have the context for command, so I'd prefer something like

```
marker = timelinemarker.new()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it after browsing through the api and checking out some other people's code.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
scene.timeline_markers.new('F_01', frame=1)
```

see [TimelineMarkers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.TimelineMarkers.html#bpy.types.TimelineMarkers) for more info